# Update entity foreign key after adding related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand how to update one record and add a related entity to that record for the first time, and then update the original record with the foreign key from the newly create related record.

For instance let's say I have two tables: One for people (tbl_person) and another for addresses (tbl_address).

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| PK | First Name | Last Name | AddressFK |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Michael    | Jordan    |         1 |
|  2 | Lebron     | James     |           |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Address tbl_Address { get; set; }

    entityBuilder
        .HasOne(t => t.tbl_Address)
        .WithOne(t => t.tbl_Person)
        .HasForeignKey<tbl_Person>(d => d.AddressID)
        .IsRequired(false);

+----+-------------------+----------+-------+
| PK |  Address Line 1   |   City   | State |
+----+-------------------+----------+-------+
|  1 | 123 Sesame Street | New York | NY    |
+----+-------------------+----------+-------+

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Person tbl_Person { get; set; }
```

My app receives the follow JSON record in need of an update.

```
{
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "789 Hollywood Ave",
    "city": "Hollywood",
    "state": "CA"
  },
  "firstname": "Lebron",
  "lastname": "Brown",
  "id": 2,
}
```

I need to update Lebron James to be Lebron Brown and also add his address. Right now I search for the record and do the following and it updates the Person record and creates an address record:

```
var person = _db.tbl_Person
    .Include(t => t.tbl_address)
    .Where(t => t.Id == json.id).First();

person.firstname = json.firstname;
person.lastname = json.lastname;
if(person.tbl_Address == null)
{
    person.tbl_Address = new tbl_Address() {
        AddressLine1 = json.address.addressLine1,
        City = json.address.city,
        State = json.address.state,
    };
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is when I try to make the person addressID equal the newly created addressID before the save changes it gives me an error regarding a foreign key constraint.

```
person.AddressID = person.tbl_Address.Id;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

**LINK TO CROSSPOST**

I ended up crossposting to the EntityFramework Core Github because I'm starting to think it might be a bug because it's not generating the Foreign Key in the child entity automatically like it supposed to.  The issues on GitHub has the sample project attached(slightly more complex than the example shown here) with the error replicated if you'd like to check it out: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5833

Comment: The class declaration with either data annotations or EntityTypeConfigurations would help, but basically you don't update the FKs manually, because at the time (before SaveChanges call) they all take the default values (`default(int) == 0`) and that's why there's an exception.

Comment: well this was more of a sample of my problem.. but it's fairly close to my actual tables. I added the class declarations as requested.

Comment: In your example, by setting `person.tbl_Address`, EF will insert the address and update the `Person` all by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your model set up correctly, you don't need to set the AddressID. It will update automatically. At the time before SaveChanges() call the AddressID's value is `default(int) == 0` - that's why the exception occurs. This declaration should suffice:

```
public class Person {
    public int AddressID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Person.AddressID))]
    public Address tbl_Address {get;set;}
}
```

tu update the address I would change the code to

```
if (json.address != null) 
{
    if(person.tbl_Address == null)
    {
        person.tbl_Address = new tbl_Address();
    }
    person.tbl_Address.AddressLine1 = json.address.addressLine1,
    person.tbl_Address.City = json.address.city,
    person.tbl_Address.State = json.address.state
}
```

this way, if person already has an address, it will update, otherwise create new. No setting of foreign keys needed - EF handles it for you.

Comment: I initially thought I didnt have to define the addressID either until I ran it and it created the address as expected but never added the addressID to the person table.  My tables are slightly different, i just dumbed down the business logic to focus on the problem but overall it's the same.  I'm making a quick dumb project to test out these sample tables to see if I get the same result

Comment: I've updated the example to perform update/insert as needed.

Comment: I ended up crossposting to the EntityFramework Core Github because I'm starting to think it might be a bug because it's not generating the Foreign Key in the child entity automatically like it supposed to.  The issues on GitHub has the sample project attacked with the error replicated if you'd like to check it out: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5833

Comment: I marked this as the answer to help other people since it does answer the question. My issue tho was a bug in EntityFramework Core RC2 Final. Initially I didn't attempt to explicitly assign the FK because historically I knew Entity Framework should handle it as you described.  After updating to the latest RTM bits, my table properly updates now

Answer (score 0):

In EF there is two ways to set a relationship,

- **Setting the FK property**: Use this variant when the entity already exist in your DB.
- **Setting the navigation property**: Use this variant in case is a new entity. When you call `SaveChanges`, the new entity is persisted in your DB and the FK column will be set too.

So, if that `Address` already exist, the only you need to do is search its `Id` and set the FK property in your `Person` entity.

If the `Address` doesn't exist, then create a new instance and call `SaveChanges`:

```
person.tbl_Address = new tbl_Address() {
    AddressLine1 = json.address.addressLine1,
    City = json.address.city,
    State = json.address.state,
};
db.SaveChanges();
```

After that call you should be able to see that `AddressId` has a value in your `Person` entity.

Comment: but in my case, where the person exists and the address doesnt exist what do I do? I need to update the lastname of the person and navigate to the address and add an address for the first time but also return that addressID to the person and update that table

Comment: Hi @chris, did you see the last part of my answer?

Comment: I ended up crossposting to the EntityFramework Core Github because I'm starting to think it might be a bug because it's not generating the Foreign Key in the child entity automatically like it supposed to.  The issues on GitHub has the sample project attacked with the error replicated if you'd like to check it out: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5833